# Confused about behavior when reading stdin c++

Tags: c++, hashmap, stdout, stdin

I am attempting to solve a problem to improve my C++ skills. I have come across some unusual behavior and I am not sure why it is happening.

I initially parsed the stdin and sorted it into a map with a key and a matching element (value). I then want to read a list of keys and output the element (value). However, for some of the key names it returns the correct value but for others it does not, but, if I hard code the intended key it works.

I know I am parsing correctly since the correct key and value are in the map as shown at the end of my output.

I assume it is an issue with reading stdin since the boolean `str.compare("tag1.tag2~name") == 0` never evaluates to 0.

The code is as follows:

```
//'it' is the name of my map
//q = 3

     for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
     {    
         getline(cin, str);
         if (str.compare("tag1.tag2~name") == 0)
         {
            cout << "key is found" << endl;
         }
         else
         {
            cout << "'" << str << "'" << endl;
         }

         if (it.count(str) == 0)
         {
             cout << "Not Found!" << endl;
         }
         else
         {
            cout << it[str] << endl;
         }
     }

    map<string, string>::iterator ptr;
    cout << "\nThe map it is : \n"; 
    cout << "\tKEY\tELEMENT\n"; 
    for (ptr = it.begin(); ptr != it.end(); ++ptr) { 
        cout << '\t' << ptr->first 
              <<"\t" +  ptr->second << "\n"; 
    } 
    return 0;
```

The output is:

```
'tag1.tag2~name
Not Found!
'tag1~name
Not Found!
'tag1~value'
HelloWorld

The map it is :
        KEY     ELEMENT
        tag1.tag2~name  Name1
        tag1~value      HelloWorld
```

The input is :

```
tag1.tag2~name
tag1~name
tag1~value
```

Thank you! I have been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: Did you try looking at the raw `char` data of `str` with a debugger? The fact that `compare()` is not returning 0 means `str` does not contain what you think it does. Try wrapping your output strings in quotes to see if there is any hidden whitespace, eg: `cout << "key is '" << str << "'" << endl; ... cout << "\t'" << ptr->first << "'"`. Also, why are you using `compare()` instead of `operator==`? Also, you are not validating that `getline()` is even successful before evaluating the contents of `str`

Comment: Maybe there is a space on the end of the line.

Comment: @drescherjm I think it's more likely to be a newline.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I checked for whitespace, still not sure what is causing the issue, i believe it might be from the input output buffer, what do you think, check the OP for the new output. Thanks!

Comment: Then you need to look at the actual `char` data inside the `str`, there is clearly a difference present, whether you can see it visually on the console terminal or not. Does `str.size() == 14`? Does `str[0] == 't'`, `str[1] == 'a'`, ... `str[13] == 'e'`? This is a good time to learn how to do some basic debugging.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just ran the code with visual studio Code and noticed that it is working as expected, I suspect it is something with the input. When I run `./a.out < input.txt` I get that unusual behavior but when I read the input from a text file using `ifstream file("input.txt");` it works what do you think?

Comment: @YoursTruly I think you need to learn how to debug your code so you can see for yourself EXACTLY what is really going on